# Regex to select indented lines preceded by one top blank line not working in Vim

Tags: regular-expression

I made the regex:

```
/^\n\t(\n|.)*?\n$/gm
```

(prepended with \v inside Vim) to select consecutively indented lines (with tab) separated by a top blank line.

But while it works in other languages it doesn't seem to do in Vim.

I expect to get the following "underlined" parts highlighted:

```
A random fact:
_
____this_______
________should_
____be_________
____highlighted
_
Another random fact:
    this
        should
    NOT
    be
    highlighted
```

But what I get is:

```
A random fact:
_
____this_______
________should_
____be_________
____highlighted
_
_Another_random_fact:
____this_______
________should_
____NOT________
____be_________
____highlighted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming `*?` is some other regex flavor's "non-greedy `*`"… don't try to translate other regexes into Vim patterns. Instead, read `:help pattern`; the syntaxes for some things are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the last `\n` is eaten by the first occurrence

```
/^\n\t\(\n\|.\){-}\ze^\n/g
```

Or:

```
/\v^\n\t(\n|.){-}\ze^\n/g
```

Or:

```
/\v^\n\t\_.{-}\ze^\n/g
```

The `{-}` replace the `*` make the repetition non-greedy to avoid that two consecutive blocks are treated like one.

The `\ze` make the the last `\n` is not eaten.

The `^\n` search for an ending blank line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a BUG in the given regex.

The given regex `/^\n\t(\n|.)*?\n$/gm` is going to match "newline & tab" at the starting , then it is going to match "newline or other character" which works across lines & hence it matches the lines which start with "other character" because that will be Preceded by "newline" !

Solution :
`/^\n\t.*(\n\t.*)*\n$/gm`
What this regex is trying :
Match "newline & tab" followed by "other characters" , then match "newline & tab" followed by "other characters" , terminating in "newline" not followed by "tab" which is the correct regex.

This will work.